# In R, how can I plot x,y values over time (3D or animation)?

Tags: r, plot

I have X and Y coordinates recorded from mouse movement on a screen. I also have the Time at which the position was recorded. I'd like to plot these showing how the mouse moved over time.

Here is a snippet of what my data frame looks like:

```
      X   Y          Time
1   812 257 1339892810683
2   793 275 1339892810709
3   783 284 1339892810732
4   746 308 1339892810771
```

I'm thinking that the only two ways to represent this accurately would be a 3D plot, or an animation that essentially represents the playback. Anybody know how to do this in R? Or, any other ideas on how this can be visualized?

Comment: maybe take a look at the `googleVis` package ...

Comment: @BenBolker - Thanks--I posted an answer with a code sample that works using googleVis. The API is very easy to work with.

Answer (score 5):

For 3D plotting I recommend the [**rgl**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgl/index.html) library.

```
install.packages("rgl") # if you don't have it
library(rgl)
plot3d(yourData$X,yourData$Y,yourData$Time)
```

That would give you a scatter plot, but I reckon that you also should be able to get it to draw lines to represent time. One cool feature is that you can change the point-of-view by dragging the mouse about.

Comment: It works. I had to subtract 1339892810000 from each of my time values to make it work, but the result is usable. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do an animation then there is the animation package, or an animate contrel for the GUI created using the `tkexamp` function in the TeachingDemos package.  You could enhance the animation by plotting the last several points with a color gradient using `color.scale.lines` from the plotrix package.

Here is an example:

```
library(TeachingDemos)
library(plotrix)

tmpfun <- function(start,numpoints=10) {
    plot(ccc$Lon,ccc$Lat, xlab='Longitute', ylab='Lattitude', type='n')
    to <- min(nrow(ccc), start+numpoints)
    color.scale.lines( ccc$Lon[start:to], ccc$Lat[start:to], 
        c(0.7,0), c(0.7,0), c(0.7,0), colvar=seq_len(numpoints) )
}

tmplist <- list( numpoints=list('spinbox', init=10, from=1, to=nrow(ccc)),
                 start=list('animate',init=1, from=1, to=nrow(ccc)) )

tkexamp( tmpfun, tmplist )
```

Here is a second example that takes time into account:

```
tmpfun2 <- function(start, dur=120) {
    time <- as.numeric(h2h$Time3)
    fr <- which( time >= start )[1]
    if( is.na(fr) ) fr <- nrow(h2h)-1
    to <- which( time >= start+dur )[1]
    if( is.na(to) ) to <- nrow(h2h)
    plot(h2h$Lon, h2h$Lat, xlab='Longitute', ylab='Lattitude',
     type='n', main=paste('Times',time[fr],'to',time[to]) )
    color.scale.lines( h2h$Lon[fr:to], h2h$Lat[fr:to], 
        c(0.7,0), c(0.7,0), c(0.7,0), colvar=time[fr:to])
}

tmplist2 <- list( dur=list('spinbox', init=120, from=10, to=1200),
                start=list('animate',init=0, from=0, to=1780, delay=100,
                            resolution=10) )

tkexamp( tmpfun2, tmplist2 )
```

Playing around with the colors in either example may give a more meaningful color gradient.

Comment: That solution animates X and Y nicely. However, it ignores the time aspect. Is there a way to incorporate Time into the playback?

Comment: One simple option to include time is to change the `colvar` argument in `color.scale.lines` to your time variable.  You could also change the tmpfun function so that it subsets on a starting time and time interval rather than point indexes.

Answer (score 3):

You could make a plot from each time instance, save the plot to a gif file, and use an application like [gifsicle](http://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/) to create the animation from all the instances/plots.

Answer (score 3):

Per Ben Bolker's suggestion, I also looked at googleVis. It's probably the least work. I had to add an "Entity" column to satisfy the requirements of the motion chart API.

```
df$Entity = rep("Mouse", nrow(df))
library(googleVis)
M <- gvisMotionChart(df, "Entity", "Time",
                 options=list(width=400, height=360))
plot(M)
```

The code worked fine, even leaving the Time column as an integer--it doesn't have to correspond to an actual time object. The only downside is that the code runs in the browser with (apparently) no easy way to save it.

Answer (score 0):

@Jim, I apologise for the plug but if you are still looking for an answer, the app that I developed was designed for exactly that purpose. It's called [popcharts](http://popchartsapp.com) and it's Mac only. It's not a free app but take a look at the website there are lot's of [demos](http://popchartsapp.com) and [tutorials](http://popchartsapp.com/tutorials/) available. But basically, if your file is structured as it is in your question, it should take you no longer than a few minutes to see your data animated and even export it to video. So I may not know how to do this in R but this will get the job done quickly.